# How to stop writing to socket (AF_LOCAL/UNIX, SOCK_STREAM) if client can't cope (buffer++)?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, blocking, unix-socket

I have a small application which uses Unix Domain Sockets to communicate data to a client.
The type of the socket is SOCK_STREAM and it's set to blocking mode (default). I'm having a bit of a trouble with a particular case when the client is lazy and can't cope with the data I'm writing to the socket -- the buffer is tending to get full and I will block in write(), thing which I want to avoid.

I have tried using select/pselect by calling this before a write() in order to see if I can do a write() or not. Things are working only half way, in the sense that I am notified that I cannot write() anymore (select returns 0 when the buffer reaches a certain size) but afterwards, when the client is able to read again, select/pselect doesn't notify this (I was expecting to return back 1 and then I could do write()).

Do you have any ideas on this matter?

Thank you!

EDIT:

server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define SV_SOCK_PATH "/tmp/srv_sk_stream"
#define BACKLOG 1
#define MAXWRITE 1000
#define TOMSEC 1000

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int sfd, cfd = -1;
    ssize_t numRead;
    char buffer[30];
    int i = 0;
    ssize_t retValWrite = -1;
    numRead = sizeof(buffer);
    if(argc !=2 ) {printf("Give the sleep value argument (msec)!\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    int sleepTime = atoi(argv[1]) * TOMSEC;
    fd_set writeFdSet;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    struct timespec ts;
    ts.tv_sec = 0;
    ts.tv_nsec = 0;

    /* create socket */
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1) {perror("FAILED creating a socket!"); return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    if (remove(SV_SOCK_PATH) == -1 && errno != ENOENT) {perror("FAILED removing old socket fd! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    /* prepare it */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1);

    /* bind it */
    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1) {perror("FAILED bind! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    /* start to listen */
    if (listen(sfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {perror("FAILED listen! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    while(i<MAXWRITE) {
        int bytesToRead = 0;
        retValWrite = -13;


        /* block in accept until a client connects (only one) */
        if (-1 == cfd) {
            cfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);
            if (cfd == -1) {perror("FAILED accept! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}
            FD_ZERO(&writeFdSet);
            FD_SET(cfd, &writeFdSet);
        }

        //ioctl(cfd,FIONREAD,&bytesToRead);
        //printf("---------> SND_BUFF has %d bytes left to be read\n", bytesToRead);

        sprintf(buffer, "PING FROM SERVER %d", i);
        /* write to the client's socket */
        int retValSelect = 0;
        errno = 0;
        retValSelect = select(cfd+1, NULL, &writeFdSet, NULL, &tv);
        //perror("ERRNO from pselect: ");
        if (retValSelect > 0) {
            int retValFdIsSet = 0;
            retValFdIsSet = FD_ISSET(cfd, &writeFdSet);
            //perror("FD_ISSET - ");
            if(retValFdIsSet) {
                retValWrite = write(cfd, buffer, numRead);
                if (retValWrite == 0 ) {
                    printf("Written 0 bytes\n");
                } else if (retValWrite < 0) {
                    perror("Error writiing to socket!\n");
                }

                ++i;
                printf("Written: %d \n", i);

                usleep(sleepTime);
            }
        } else  {
            printf("Wait for it... %d\n", count);
        }
    }

    /* close client socket */
    if (close(cfd) == -1) {perror("FAILED close srv socket! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    if (remove(SV_SOCK_PATH) == -1 && errno != ENOENT) {perror("FAILED removing old socket fd! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define SV_SOCK_PATH "/tmp/srv_sk_stream"
#define MAXREAD 1000
#define TOMSEC 1000

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int sfd;
    ssize_t numRead;
    char pingStr[30];
    numRead = sizeof(pingStr);
    int readCount = 0;
    if(argc !=2 ) {printf("Give the sleep value argument (msec)!\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    int sleepTime = atoi(argv[1]) * TOMSEC;

    /* create socket */
    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sfd == -1) {perror("FAILED creating a socket! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    /* prepare it */
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(addr.sun_path) - 1);

    /* connect */
    if (connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1) {perror("FAILED connecting to socket! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    while (readCount < MAXREAD) {
        char strRead[numRead];
        int bytesRead=0;
        int bytesToRead=0;

        ioctl(sfd,FIONREAD, &bytesToRead);
        printf("---------> RCV_BUFF has %d bytes left to be read\n", bytesToRead);

        /* read */
        bytesRead = read(sfd, &strRead, numRead);
        if(bytesRead == 0) {
            perror("Read 0 bytes from socket! - ");
        }
        else if (bytesRead < 0) {
            perror("FAILED reading from socket! - ");
        }
        ++readCount;
        printf("%d - READ: %s\n", readCount, strRead);
        usleep(sleepTime);
    }

    /* close */
    if (close(sfd) == -1) {perror("FAILED close clt socket! - "); return EXIT_FAILURE;}

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output for server (writing at 100 msec)

```
./srvstream 100
Written: 1 
Written: 2 
Written: 3 
Written: 4 
Written: 5 
Written: 6 
Written: 7 
Written: 8 
Written: 9 
Written: 10 
Written: 11 
Written: 12 
Written: 13 
Written: 14 
Written: 15 
Written: 16 
Written: 17 
Written: 18 
Written: 19 
Written: 20 
Written: 21 
Written: 22 
Written: 23 
Written: 24 
Written: 25 
Written: 26 
Written: 27 
Written: 28 
Written: 29 
Written: 30 
Written: 31 
Written: 32 
Written: 33 
Written: 34 
Written: 35 
Written: 36 
Written: 37 
Written: 38 
Written: 39 
Written: 40 
Written: 41 
Written: 42 
Written: 43 
Written: 44 
Written: 45 
Written: 46 
Written: 47 
Written: 48 
Written: 49 
Written: 50 
Written: 51 
Written: 52 
Written: 53 
Written: 54 
Written: 55 
Written: 56 
Written: 57 
Written: 58 
Written: 59 
Written: 60 
Written: 61 
Written: 62 
Written: 63 
Written: 64 
Written: 65 
Written: 66 
Written: 67 
Written: 68 
Written: 69 
Written: 70 
Written: 71 
Written: 72 
Written: 73 
Written: 74 
Written: 75 
Written: 76 
Written: 77 
Written: 78 
Wait for it... 0
Wait for it... 0
Wait for it... 0
Wait for it... 0
Wait for it... 0
------->8-------- stays this way even after the client reports consumes the whole buffer
```

client (reading at 1 sec.):

```
./cltstream 1000
---------> RCV_BUFF has 0 bytes left to be read
1 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 0
---------> RCV_BUFF has 270 bytes left to be read
2 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 1
---------> RCV_BUFF has 540 bytes left to be read
3 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 2
---------> RCV_BUFF has 810 bytes left to be read
4 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 3
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1080 bytes left to be read
5 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 4
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1350 bytes left to be read
6 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 5
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1620 bytes left to be read
7 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 6
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1890 bytes left to be read
8 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 7
---------> RCV_BUFF has 2100 bytes left to be read
9 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 8
---------> RCV_BUFF has 2070 bytes left to be read
10 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 9
---------> RCV_BUFF has 2040 bytes left to be read
11 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 10
---------> RCV_BUFF has 2010 bytes left to be read
12 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 11
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1980 bytes left to be read
13 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 12
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1950 bytes left to be read
14 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 13
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1920 bytes left to be read
15 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 14
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1890 bytes left to be read
16 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 15
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1860 bytes left to be read
17 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 16
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1830 bytes left to be read
18 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 17
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1800 bytes left to be read
19 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 18
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1770 bytes left to be read
20 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 19
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1740 bytes left to be read
21 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 20
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1710 bytes left to be read
22 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 21
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1680 bytes left to be read
23 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 22
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1650 bytes left to be read
24 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 23
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1620 bytes left to be read
25 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 24
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1590 bytes left to be read
26 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 25
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1560 bytes left to be read
27 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 26
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1530 bytes left to be read
28 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 27
---------> RCV_BUFF has 1500 bytes left to be read
29 - READ: PING FROM SERVER 28
-----------8<------------ -- continues this way until RCV_BUFF has 0 bytes left and then blocks
```

Comment: Select should return that the socket is writable once the peer read enough data from the socket so that it is room to write more. If this is not the case for you I would suggest a coding error, but it is hard to say without code.

Comment: Just added my code. Thank you!

Comment: The server code does not make much sense for me: It will accept a new client and then just issue one single write - because it did not write anything to the socket before the send buffer cannot be full and thus the select will return that the socket is writable in all cases. So write will be successful, even if not everything from the buffer will be written (but it will not block). Can you really reproduce your problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: Added my output. The server waits for one client to connect then tries to write for MAXWRITE times. If select returns 0 it will skip calling write().

Comment: You set writeFdSet once after accepting (BTW, it's irritating that you do the accept inside the loop). But select changes writeFdSet, e.g. it will remove the Fd from the set if it is not writable. So for all remaining selects you just expect nothing (empty writeFdSet). The other thing is that you wait with a timeout of 0, e.g do a busy loop. You should use either NULL as timeout (wait until success or interrupt) or set it to the maximum time you want to wait.

Comment: That was it, I had the empty writeFdSet! Having it set again will do what I needed. Thank you very much Steffen! P.S.: I know it's ugly with the accept in the loop, this code was written ad-hoc just to test part of the bigger system, there is better :) Also, thanks for the hints regarding the timeout!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in blocking mode, write() and send() won't return -1/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK if the send buffer is full. They will block. You need non-blocking mode if you want to handle those conditions.

Comment: I would still like to have a mechanism which would avoid calling write/send if the client's buffer is full. Also, I cannot rely on the client to tell me 'hey, give me something, my buffer is empty now', I would prefer to treat it all on server side.

Comment: select() tells you when the buffer is full, but it doesn't tell you when the (unknown) amount of data you're about to write will more than fill the buffer, which is what causes blocking. It can't know that. Only you can know that.